# Can I use a Lantern of Shadows at the same time as Blade Hands or alternate forms?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I know that followers of Ashenzari can get the skill benefits of a cursed enhancer staff while still using unarmed attack skill/damage if transformed into an alternate form, so this got me wondering if I could do something similar with the shadow summoning benefits of a Lantern of Shadows while using blade hands or alternate transfiguration forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the lantern of shadows will "fall away", not meld, with transformations. I'm not sure if that's been changed; I'm using trunk, and it seems lanterns of shadow have even been removed, so I'm just going by "miscellaneous evocable wieldable item" as a basis (such as rods).

Comment: Really bums me out how much stuff they remove sometimes. I miss the stalker class a lot.